# Font looks sharper in VS Code compared to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Probably better to show by image here:

[image: Image for comparison]

The color, the sharpness of the text, everything seems better in VS Code than in Visual Studio.

Is there any settings I can play with, or this is just how it is?

Comment: Different font.  Tools > Options > Environment > Font and Colors to pick the one you like.

Comment: It is the same font, both are Fira font.

Comment: Belongs in the question.  As does the current zoom rate.  If it is the same font then it does a poor job at hinting, not unusual for an open source font because it is the one million dollar option.  Pick the one you like, Consolas scales well for example.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while I was trying to solve this problem myself, same font looking much more readable in VS Code compared to Visual Studio.

What worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 is extension called [Text Sharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.TextSharp).

I use Consolas, and these settings finally made the font look the same in both editors:
[image]